# Can history expansion (exclamation mark) be disabled on Windows shell?

Tags: cmd, escaping

When I run a command like this:

```
someprogram.exe --param="Value!"
```

the Windows shell will treat the exclamation mark in my value as a special character. Is there a way to suppress that or is escaping the only way around this? (Exclamation mark is escaped by `^^!` if I'm not mistaken.)

**EDIT**: Weird thing that `cmd.exe` does not do the expansion but [cmder](http://bliker.github.io/cmder/) does. I thought they are just two different GUIs to the same underlying shell? Maybe there's a switch for the expansion behavior? I tried `SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion` but with no effect.

Comment: what if you use quotes instead of double quotes ?

Comment: Windows shell doesn't support single quotes.

Comment: uhm ?? try this `notepad 'c:\temp\test!.txt'`

Comment: Sorry, I meant that it sometimes causes problems, see e.g. http://superuser.com/questions/324278/how-to-make-windows-command-prompt-treat-single-quote-as-though-it-is-a-double-q. In my specific case where single quotes are used around parameters passed to [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org), also only double quotes work.

Comment: Same problem... it's driving me CRAZY